# Run XST from Windows Command Line

Tags: xilinx, ise

I am attempting to build a C++ program that performs all of the necessary steps generate a bit file using the ISE (14.7) tool chain. I generate the Command line Log File for my project and try to run all of the commands by hand on the command line. When I try to run the XST command I need the GUI generated .xst script, .syr report file and the .prj file.

I believe that in theory I should be able to complete syntheses with these however I get

ERROR:Xst:439 - No write access in xst/projnav.tmp

The GUI creates an xst folder with projnav.tmp when xst is run. It seems that running xst from command line doesn't

Is there a command or xst argument to have this folder made?

Comment: Is this program running on Windows or Linux? Have you loaded the Xilinx environment? As I already wrote, we have implemented all this in [PoC](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC). So you could look into our Python code :). For example see [XSTCompiler.py](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/py/Compiler/XSTCompiler.py)

Comment: @Paebbels It is running on windows. I want my C++ application to do all the necessary steps to generate a bit file then analyze it. Based on the analysis modify the constraints in the UCF and start over. Is it safe to say PoC will control xst, ngdbuild, bitgen, etc to allow me to do this?

Comment: PoC is running on Windows and Linux. Currently we only support XST in the ISE flow and Vivado Synthesis in the Vivado flow. You can define multiple HDL files as an input as well as UCF files for constraints and a xst option file. We also support ISE Core Generator to generate a DDR RAM controller, which outputs VHDL or Verilog sources, which are then combined to a netlist. PoC's Python infrastructure is modular and could be extended with further steps towards a bit-file. PoC has also a build in filter design to categorize log and report messages and to scan for important result lines.